# Indices of the N smallest values in a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, vector, stl

I have a `QVector<float>` and I need to get an array of iterators/pointers to the best (minimum) N values from it. How can I do that, preferably using the STL algorithms?

Comment: Please define meaning of "best" (e.g., maximum values).

Comment: Oh well, I mean the minimum values.

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Best way to do this is to have your `QVector` sorted in ascending order and then take first `N` values.

Comment: You start by taking out a piece of paper, and a pen, and writing down your proposed algorithm, in a logical manner, for implementing this task. If you cannot do that, your question has nothing to do with C++, but would be an algorithm question. If you can, but can't figure how to translate the logical algorithm into C++, then it would be a C++ question. Once you have figured out what your problem is, you can update your question, accordingly, and indicate if you have a ***specific*** C++ or algorithm question.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but since I want to learn more about STL, I asked that question.

Comment: Sounds like work for `std::nth_element` or maybe `std::partial_sort`

Comment: Is your vector allowed to be changed? (Or is it sorted)

Comment: No, it's just a list of times.

Comment: `std::partial_sort_copy` then.

Comment: But how to get a vector of pointers to the best values instead of the best values themselves?

Comment: There isn't an stl function to get a vector of pointers or iterators to the values. You would have to create a vector of iterators to all elements in the array and then use something like `std::nth_element` or `std::partial_sort` with a custom comparator on that, and then use the first n iterators out of that vector.

Answer (score 5):

There is a simple way to give you **a vector of best N indices** (not only values) as you want.
It is much similar to Igor's answer, but it gives you a result vector with exactly N best indices.

This code is really simple and uses the power of **STL**, just like you requested. Take a look:

```
QVector<int> findBestIndices(QVector<float> &times, const int &N)
{   
    QVector<int> indices(times.size());
    std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0); // fill with 0,1,2,...

    std::partial_sort(indices.begin(), indices.begin()+N, indices.end(),
                     [&times](int i,int j) {return times[i]<times[j];});

    return QVector<int>(indices.begin(), indices.begin()+N);
}

int main()
{
    QVector<float> times = {3.14, 0.29, 3.50, 59.38, 2.39};

    const int N = 3; // N best times
    QVector<int> best = findBestIndices(times, N);

    for(const auto &index : best) {
        std::cout << '#' << index << " => " << times[index] << "s\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will print:

```
#1 => 0.29s
#4 => 2.39s
#0 => 3.14s
```

---

Still, if you ever wanted to do the same, but values would be enough...
You can obtain a sorted vector of your best elements by using `std::partial_sort_copy` function:

```
const int N = 3;
QVector<float> best(N);
QVector<float> times = {3.14, 0.29, 3.50, 59.38, 2.39};

std::partial_sort_copy(times.begin(), times.end(), best.begin(), best.end());

for(const auto &mytime : best) std::cout << mytime << '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
QVector<float> data;  // populated somehow
int N; // some value <= data.size()

std::vector<int> indices;
int i = 0;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(indices), data.size(),
  [&i]() { return i++; });

std::partial_sort(indices.begin(), indices.begin() + N, indices.end(),
  [&data](int ind1, int ind2) { return data[ind1] < data[ind2]; });
/* Now indices[0] through indices[N-1] contain indices
   of the N smallest elements in data. */
```